# restaurant menu card tutorial for drupal?

Tags: drupal

im new on drupal and want to make a menu for a restaurant showing all the dishes with photos, prices and descriptions in categories (japanese food, chinese food etc).

i wonder if there are some great tutorials or modules for this?

i cant find any on the web.

thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new content type called `dish`. Use CCK to add the following fields to your `dish` content type:

- CCK File Field (image field) for your Photo, call this food_photo
- CCK Money field for your price, call this food_price
- CCK Text field for your description, call this food_description

Create a new vocabulary called `foodcategories`. Add all of your "japanese food", "chinese food", "italian food" etc to this, and allow the node type `dish`.

Create a View of type node. Filter the view to node type `dish`. Select the fields food_photo, food_price and food_description, node title and taxonomy term from the vocabulary `foodcategories`. Group by the taxonomy term field. Order by the node title field ascending or by price, whatever.

That's as much of the answer as I can be bothered typing out.

Comment: what field type should i use for photo? and there is two fields in "manage fields" that i can add: "new field" and "new group". which is it? thanks

Comment: That's basically all that can be said too. @fayer: File/ImageField. You probably want to add a field only, not a group.

Comment: there is no ImageField field. only: decimal, float, integer, node reference, text, user reference. which should i choose?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use CCK and Views. There are tons of good tutorials about this. I recommend Learn By The Drop - it's really easy to follow.

Comment: is that about how to create resturang menues? cause i want tutorials focusing on that to save time.

Comment: No, it's mainly about how Views work. You can use that knowledge to create a menu.